# Azure Websites and Virtual Network

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Will Azure Websites support virtual network in the future. To enable an Azure Website to connect to VM:s and Cloud Services using a local ip within Azure instead of needing to open up the servers and services to everyone by using the public IP.

Is that something that's actively being developed or is such a feature way into the future. Or both.

Comment: We're not Azure and have nothing to do with Azure. You should be asking them for their development roadmap.

Comment: Yes, it already exists. Use "Resource Manager" not classic templates. There is no way to route between the two

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a general feature request (for a feature that already exists). It has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think feature has been there for a while, please checkout below article

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-websites-virtual-network-integration/

Quote:

> Azure Websites is happy to announce support for integration between
>   your Azure VNET and your Azure Websites. While you cannot place your
>   Azure Website in an Azure VNET, the Virtual Network feature grants
>   your website access to resources running your VNET.  This includes
>   being able to access web services or databases running on your Azure
>   Virtual Machines. If your VNET is connected to your on premise network
>   with Site to Site VPN, then your Azure Website will now be able to
>   access on premise systems through the Azure Websites Virtual Network
>   feature.  This feature is currently in Preview and will continue to be
>   improved on the road to GA.